# were to vs past participle

Tags: meaning

I have read about **were to** in http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html that **were to** can be used in the sense of **present**,**past**and **future.** The website describes about **were to** as follows:

**Were to in the Present**

> FORM
>
> **[If ... were to + verb ..., ...]**
>
> USE
>
> **Were to can be used in the present to emphasize that the conditional form is extremely unlikely or unthinkably horrible. Notice that this special form is only used in the if-clause.**
>
> Examples:
>
> If she were to be rich, she would be horribly obnoxious.
>   *It is very unlikely that she would be rich.*
>
> If I were to have no friends, who would I spend my time with?
>   *Having no friends is a horrible thought.*
>
> If Nathan were to be my boss, this job would be intolerable.
>   *Nathan's being my boss is a horrible concept.*

**Were to in the Future**

> FORM
>
> **[If ... were to + verb ..., ...]**
>
> USE
>
> **Were to can be used in the future to emphasize that the conditional form is extremely unlikely or unthinkably horrible. Notice that this special form is only used in the if-clause.**
>
> Examples:
>
> If I were to lose my job next year, I would probably not find a new one quickly.
>   *Losing my job would be terrible.*
>
> If he were to fail his driving test tomorrow, he would have to take it again.
>   *He is not likely to fail his driving test.*
>
> If Sarah were to show up late to the birthday party, it would ruin the surprise.
>   *Sarah will surely come on time.*

**Were to in the Past**

> FORM
>
> **[If ... were to have + past participle ..., ...]**
>
> USE
>
> **Were to can be used in the past to emphasize that the conditional form is extremely unlikely or unthinkably horrible. Notice that this special form is only used in the if-clause.**
>
> Examples:
>
> If the fire were to have destroyed the building, it would have been a tragic cultural loss.
>   *The thought of such a loss is too horrible to consider.*
>
> If the dam were to have burst , the entire town would have been destroyed.
>   *Such destruction is too horrible to consider.*
>
> If Sarah were to have failed the final test, she would have lost her scholarship.
>   *She is an excellent student, and it is very unlikely that she would have failed the test.*

Can I use second form of verb or past participle in the place of **were to** without changing the meaning of sentences? If it conveys the same meanings as 'were to' does, Can I use simple past instead of using 'were to' ?

**For present**

> If she became rich, she would be horribly obnoxious.
>
> If I didn't have friends, who would I spend my time with?

**For past**

> If the fire had destroyed the building, it would have been a tragic cultural loss.
>
> If Sarah had failed the final test, she would have lost her scholarship.

**For future**

> If I lost my job next year, I would probably not find a new one quickly.
>
> If he failed his driving test tomorrow, he would have to take it again.

Comment: Please learn to properly format your posts. Quotes should be in quote blocks and giant walls of text are not easy to read. You have been here long enough to learn these things. Please stop expecting them to be done for you.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Option for Using Bold or block letter to edit question isn't available in mobile device, whereas I'm using mobile device.

Sorry for that.

Comment: You can make text bold by surrounding it with double asterisks. `**bold text**` --> **bold text**

Comment: You saw I tried to make letter bold but I failed, only * is being shown instead of being bold

Comment: Please wait for a while, I'm trying to fix it

Comment: I think I've made it bold

Comment: There is no need for the examples to be so LONG.

Comment: I am just trying to show the Same examples from the website content where there has been used "were to", and I want to use 'past form of verb" in the place of "were to" in the same examples to make the question clear and understandable.
As a result the examples happened to be long

Comment: There is no need to copy nearly the entire web page into your question. The link and one or two examples are all that is necessary, especially for such an uncomplicated question.

Comment: Also: please understand that _were to_ is not reserved _only_ for unlikely or horrible speculative events. You are just as liable to see _"If you were to buy a Chevy, I wouldn't mind."_ Also: if you don't know how to conjugate an irregular verb (like _to lose_) look it up (_losed_ is not the participle of _to lose._). Also: _loosing_ is not the gerund of _to lose._ This error is present on the so-called "Englishpage" website, and you copied it here.

Answer (score -2):

This question is very simple: **If + were to [verb (except be)]** has exactly the same meaning as: **If + simple past + to + verb**. However, please bear with me.

1) If **I were to go tomorrow**, I would see him = **If I went tomorrow**, I would see him.

2) Your example, however, /If she **were to be** rich, she would be horribly obnoxious/ is not really grammatical.

Grammatically, one would write: **If she were rich**, she would be horribly obnoxious. And **If Nathan were my boss, etc.**

3) Your example: /If I were to have  no friends etc./ is less awkward if written as: If I **had** no friends, who would I spend time with?

3) That said, **If + were + to be [past participle]** is another case.

**If she were to be arrested**, that would be a problem.

**If + were to be [action verb]** is not **If + were [rich, poor,** etc.]. That is to say: were + a state or condition.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about _"If she were to be rich, she would be horribly obnoxious."_ It's misbegotten, and no native speaker would write or say it, but it's grammatical.

Comment: P. E. Dant  It is not standard grammar and would be edited down by any good editor to: If she were rich. The OP said: [If ... were to + verb ..., ...] that would be: if the boy were to GO, if the girl were to SAY. So, I clarified it. And correctly so.

Comment: There's an important difference, though, between being in need of editing and being _ungrammatical;_ e.g., _"If she were to be rich, she were horribly obnoxious"_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: @P.E Dent I agree with you, the answer should be edited to make it clear

Comment: @yubrajsharma Just as important, the question contains an obvious error which was pointed out in comments. Can you see it?

Comment: I think I'm mistaken, I had to write 'lost' instead of 'losed' in my examples.

Comment: How to believe an answer which has got downvotes rather than Upvotes ?

Comment: @yubraz sharma Indeed, that is the question. Perhaps you might want to take a second look at the logic I used and how I developed my argument.

Comment: @P. E. Dant Your sentence quoting me: Quote "If she were to be rich, she were horribly obnoxious" is ungrammatical. Unquote. Yes, that's right, it is. /If she were to go, she would enjoy it/ is grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie My point is that the statement _"Your example, however, /If she were to be rich, she would be horribly obnoxious/ is not really grammatical"_ is false. That sentence is certainly clumsy, and no native speaker would write or say it, but it is grammatical. This may account for the downvotes.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Yes! Well done; the verb _lose_ is irregular, and the participle is _lost._ By the way, the Englishpage.com entry which you quoted also contains a common error related to the same verb. I have corrected it in your question. Do you know what it is?

Comment: @P.E Dent sorry I don't know what the error was

Comment: @P.E Dent who would believe the answer which has downvotes ? The answer should be edited.

Comment: @yubrajsharma The englishpage.com entry has this sentence: "_Loosing_ my job would be terrible."

Comment: @P.E Dent Englishpage.com must be informed about this error,anyway, Thank you so much for your edits, Could you edit this answer too so that this answer would be helpfull for other learners too?

Comment: Reply me please

Comment: @P. E. Dant It is your opinion that it is grammatical. For me, it is not.